# Upload app bundle to google play failed without prompt

Tags: android, google-play

I had joined in the google signing play. Using diff keys for app signing and app uploading. When i used upload key to generate .aab file and upload that file to google play console. It was failed, but without any error message.
I uploaded in the internal test:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xLn.png)
The error i got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ek98.png)
If anyone had such experience? My app has targeted to android-29 and adapted to arm64.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue and It's Google's side, try again later, they may solve it soon.

Answer (score 1):

It may because i use the new google play console and it is a beta version.
I get the error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://playconsoleapps-pa.clients6.google.com/upload...' from origin 'https://play.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And everything become normal after i use the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Try to signing out from all google accounts and try signing in again.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way to resolve is to use **incognito mode** when using **a different account**